# Video tag poster overlapping Fixed Nav tag

Tags: css, carousel, nav

I've newly started to learn CSS and I was trying to fix my nav tag while scrolling using the following code:

```
nav{
background-color: #333;
overflow: hidden;
position: sticky;
top: 0px;
display: flex;
```

}

All the contents work fine except the video tag in carousel which when scrolled down overlaps the nav tag.

Comment: Try setting [z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index).

Comment: How do I do it? Like what value should I give??